# Azure role that can't create resources

Tags: azure, roles

I want to find or create an azure role that has the same capabilities as an Owner, or at the very least a contributer. But this role should not have access to create azure resources.

I've been going through the pre-defined roles that exist.

Comment: Reader? 1234567

Comment: reader cannot edit resources. he wants a role to edit them, but not create

Answer (score 2):

this makes no sense in Azure RBAC context. you cant edit but not create resources, because this is being governed by the same permission: `resource/write`.

you can achieve something like that by having a role that can do anything except writes, but that would mean that it cannot edit resources, which is not what you are after, probably.

technically you can grant contributor permissions to each individual resource, that way user wont be able to create new resources, only modify existing ones (he would be able to delete resource).

Comment: To give you a little more context:
In my company we have a custom portal used for resource creation. The reason for this is to make sure that people are compliant and that costs go to the right place. The problem with this is that accesses are only given on resource level, which makes it hard for people like me who manage solutions to get an overview. Getting access to the resource group would be better, but then there's nothing stopping people from creating resources using the Azure portal instead of our custom one.

Comment: you could examine azure policies to prevent people from creating stuff without specific tags, but honestly I think the design is flawed. you should tag resource groups, anything created inside them can still be tracked down to resource groups (for billing purposes). and then you can grant people access to create resource inside resource groups they own, but not tag resource groups or create them.

Comment: An example of a similar problem.  ADF pipelines can only be run by contributors (either resource contributors or ADF contributors).  If I have support people who need to restart pipelines, then they need that role.  By granting that role at the RG level, they can also now create new ADFs (not what we want).  In order to do this, we have to grant contributor at each ADF resource which is a management bloat pain.  It is solvable but with 100's resources, trying to minimize management and customization.

Comment: launching pipelines is probably a separate action. at least it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirements, and I managed to configure it by taking the Contributor role as base and adding

```
"Microsoft.Resources/*/write"
```

in **notActions** section of role JSON configuration.

What it does is that it prevents deployments. Every resource creation is a deployment.

As far as I have tested every "edit" operation on resources works, even deployment slot creation for Web Apps, but you can disable that too if you need.